# Index Structure in postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, pgadmin

After creating an index in pgAdmin, is it possible to view the structure of the index in order to see how the column (s) have been sorted? I want to be able to see the B tree data structure. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `B tree data structure` is a internal datastructure representation and not a view level representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't view the b-tree backing an index in PgAdmin-III. It's a low-level on-disk data structure that's entirely internal to the database backend.

You'll need to write some C code that runs inside the PostgreSQL server to explore the btree, or use the [pageinspect](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pageinspect.html) extension.